# Подгрузить папку с изображениями для обработки

Tags: python, sklearn

У меня есть папка с изобрважениями. Я хочу ее подгрузить в файл .ipynb, для чего использую данный код:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files #будем подгружать файлы с данными
import os

PATH_TO_DATA = r'C:\Users\ivan\tasks\dataset'
photos = load_files(os.path.join(PATH_TO_DATA))
```

При этом на команду `len(photos.data)` мне выдается 0, хотя в папке 9800 фото.

Вопрос: load_file для этого не подходит?

Comment: Там должна быть определенная структура папок: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html . Внутри папки `dataset` должна быть минимум одна папка с фотографиями.  У вас так?

Comment: Кст, `os.path.join` вам не нужен - он используется для соединения нескольких путей, типа `os.path.join('C:/', 'Users', 'ivan')`

Comment: я как раз одну папку и удалил((

Comment: Кст, мб вам это нужно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68506077/5909792

Comment: я похожее нашел в другом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123421/image-clustering-by-its-similarity-in-python  но что такое glob.glob вообще не понял

Comment: `glon` это поиск по шаблону, например `*` - любой файл/папка, `*.jpg` - любой файл с расширением `jpg`